# What is the $n^{th}$ binary number

Tags: binary, number-systems

After removing all binary numbers containing two successive ones, we need to find the $n^{th}$ binary number.
The series formed is 0,1,10,100,101,1000,... and we need its $n^{th}$ number.

Comment: Maybe you can use the following observation: The amount of such numbers with precisely N digits is the same as the amount of such number with $\le N-2$ digits. (since by the rules it must be of the form 10xxxxx)

Comment: A general rule on such subjects : always consult OEIS ; your sequence is there: (https://oeis.org/A003714)